# Change hover menu colour

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to change the hover menu colour of this wordpress website [http://box5666.temp.domains/~thelebd4/nsocompany/peermont/](http://box5666.temp.domains/%7Ethelebd4/nsocompany/peermont/)
i have searched for a custom way of doing it but none. i have tried this code

```
a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}
```

I want to change it from that blue colour to red
but is not working, kindly help thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should target that specific element using css. Targeting **'a'** will change all untargeted link colors.

**Add this to change default color:**

```
#quadmenu.quadmenu-default_theme .quadmenu-navbar-nav > li:not(.quadmenu-item-type-button) > a > .quadmenu-item-content{
    color:#800020 !important;
}
```

**Add this to change on hover color:**

```
#quadmenu.quadmenu-default_theme .quadmenu-navbar-nav > li:not(.quadmenu-item-type-button) > a:hover > .quadmenu-item-content{
    color:#800020 !important;
}
```

Using **!important** might lead to unwanted behaviors. To avoid using it, make sure to add these styles after the theme's css file.